# How does one player exit Halo Anniversary?

Tags: halo-anniversary

The players have no option like "leave party" and there is no way to logout like all other xbox games.  How does one leave without shutting the console off?

Comment: Guide button, Y, Up, A ?

Answer (score 5):

Hit the Xbox Guide Button on the controller of the player who wants to leave, and then hit X to sign out of the profile. Profiles are used to control split screen player count, instead of the party like system that is used in later games.